# $\alpha$, transcendental over $F$ $\implies$ $[F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^{3}]=3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F \subseteq E$ be an extension and let $\alpha \in E$ be transcendental over $F$.

Since $\alpha$ is a root for $x^{3}-\alpha^{3} \in F(\alpha^{3})[x]$, clearly $[F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^{3})]=1, 2, \text{or} \> 3$. I'm trying to rule out $1$ and $2$. I know that $F[x] \cong F[\alpha]$. But I can't see how to use that in a fruitful way.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that any cubic polynomial in $k[x]$ (for any field $k$) is reducible over $k[x]$ if and only if it has a root in $k$.

In this case, we want to show that the cubic polynomial $x^3 - \alpha^3$ is irreducible over $F(\alpha^3)[x]$. By the above observation, this is equivalent to proving that $\omega^i \alpha \not\in F(\alpha^3)$ for all $i = 0, 1, 2$ where $\omega$ is the 3rd root of unity. Now, if $\omega^i \alpha \in F(\alpha^3)$ then we can write
$$\omega^i \alpha = f(\alpha^3)/g(\alpha^3)$$
where $f, g \in F[x], g \not= 0$. But then we find that
$$\alpha^3 (g(\alpha^3))^3 = (f(\alpha^3))^3$$
and so $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, contradicting assumption that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$.